# How to set image height for all browser?

Tags: html, css

Before I posting this question I have checked this forum and google but the methods is not working for me. May be I am doing wrong.

I have a page which is look like this : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFsrw.png)

In this page I have few images and for that I am using following css code:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100% \9;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 75px;
height: auto !important;
height: 75px;
```

Now in Firefox browser both top and bottom images are showing correct size but in internet explorer all images are showing full height ( filled up entire website)!!

Now If I remove this line

```
height: auto !important;
```

then on internet explorer image height is perfect but on Firefox bottom images are stretch.

How can I solved this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: which IE version(s)?

Comment: what about removing min-height too? So that only height: 75px is left.

Comment: Can you please create a code snippet that actually reproduce this issue? Please include your HTML & CSS code... images can refer to placehold.it urls...

Comment: @StandardNerd If set only height then bottom images are stretched !

Comment: stretched horizontally or vertically or both?

Comment: What is the ` \9` at the end of your `width` property?

Comment: bottom images actual size is 118px and but it's showing 75px if I only set 75px. That's why it's stretched vertically

Comment: @Manngo how can I do this ?

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed Do what?

Comment: @Manngo ` \9` this line ?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be more helpful

Comment: Still have a height of 75px man! use 1 height class..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this.

```
{
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 75px;
    min-height: 75px;
    width: auto;
}
```

About your all image height will be 75px but width may be not same for all and if you want image also same then please use below.

```
{
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 75px;
    min-height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If all images have same width then there will no issue but if width are not same for all images then may be some images will be stretch.